# facebook android login in activity sdk v3.5

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to implement the latest facebook login activity.
I have a mainactivity and my custom button to login via facebook on click of that button it should login get user details,email,profile image and friends details .I tried the code for login given by facebook and it works only for basic details i TRIED adding permissions and still i get null for email and the rest but I get the basic details correctly .Also I am using activity and not fragments.How do I get other details also?   Please help me out.Thanks in advance.

```
public class new2 extends Activity {


    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            loginact();

        }
    });


    }

    protected void loginact() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(new2.this, "loading", "loading");

        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){



                Session.openActiveSession(new2.this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

                    // callback when session changes state
                    @Override
                    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {


                        if (session.isOpened()) {


                            Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session, new GraphUserCallback() {


                                // callback after Graph API response with user object
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {


                                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                                    if (user != null) {
                                        TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                                        welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");


                                        TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

                                        t.setText(user.getName() + ","
                                                + user.getUsername() + ","
                                                + user.getId() + "," + user.getLink()
                                                + "," + user.getFirstName()+ user.asMap().get("email"));

                                    //  String email = (String) response.getGraphObject().getProperty("email");

                                        Log.w("user", user.toString());

                                        Log.w("response", response.toString());


                                        Log.w("email",  user.asMap().get("email").toString());

                                    }
                                }



                            }
                                    );



                            String NAME = "name";
                            String ID = "id";
                            String PICTURE = "picture";
                            String EMAIL = "email";
                            String FRIENDS = "read_friendlists";
                            String FIELDS = "fields";
                            String REQUEST_FIELDS = TextUtils.join(",", new String[] {
                                    ID, NAME, PICTURE, EMAIL,FRIENDS
                            });

                            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                            parameters.putString(FIELDS, REQUEST_FIELDS);
                            request.setParameters(parameters);              
                            Request.executeBatchAsync(request);


                        }
                    }
                });


            }
        }

                ).start();
    }





@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: "but it crashed." tells us nothing- What does your LogCat say?

Comment: user.asMap().get("email") is null (null pointer exception)

Comment: Thanks for looking into it running on android tablet

Comment: In your second attempt (with `onSessionStateChange()`), where do you try to open a session?

Comment: if you have anycode which works then attach the link to it. Thanks.Struggling to get it to work

Comment: Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17977621/1253844

Comment: posting editted code now .I tried many things and finally the state is this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40756/discussion-between-jason-and-tanis-7x)

Comment: @Tanis.7x I have updated the code .PLease look into it.

Comment: I tried the code which you suggested .I am not receiving the email id.Please help

Comment: I'm not seeing a call to `setPermissions("basic_info", "email");` in your code.

Comment: I am sorry i have the app in sandbox .will anything change now ?